# Call Twirl template in scala code

Tags: scala, templates, playframework-2.0, twirl

I have a Play Scala 2.5 application.  I would like to know how to return Twirl template (if possible) inside another Twirl template from scala code.

Example : I have several Twirl templates corresponding to html input element.  One template for input text, another for input checkbox and so on.
I have a main template and inside I call a helper method from a Scala object or class and based on some condition I return the Twirl template for the wanted input element.

Comment: Do you mean with same input parameters or totally different templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this answer I suppose that your templates have the same input parameters and output type(HTML). [Play docs](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaTemplates#overview) say that templates are compiled to normal Scala functions.

For example, let's say you have two templates, *template1* and *template2*, and they both have input parameter `a: String`. The *main* template should use either of those two, so it has a parameter of `template: String => HtmlFormat.Appendable`.

**template1**:

```
@(a: String)
@{ a + " world!" }
```

**template2**:

```
@(a: String)
@{ a + " Stackoverflow!" }
```

**main**:

```
@(template: String => HtmlFormat.Appendable)
@template("Hello")
```

If we pass *template1* we get "Hello world!", and if we pass *template2* we get "Hello Stackoverflow!".

Now, you could define a **method** `getTemplate` to get the wanted template:

```
val t1 = views.html.template1.apply _
val t2 = views.html.template2.apply _

def getTemplate(param: Int) = if(param == 1) t1 else t2
```

and finally the `Application` **controller** method:

```
def showTemplate(param: Int) = Action {
  val template = getTemplate(param)
  Ok(views.html.mainTemplate(template))
}
```

and **route**, of course:

```
GET     /template/:id               controllers.Application.showTemplate(id: Int)
```

Comment: Thank you for your nice answer.  For your question about parameters, yes my Twirl templates for input elements have different parameters.

Comment: No easy points here, heh... I suppose you will need to move your logic inside template itself or something like that...